# Serde deserialize one item or list of items

Tags: rust, serde

I have the following document:

```yaml
changes:
  abc: !add 3
  def:
    - !add 1
    - !remove 2
```

As you can see the value of the field can either be an action or a list of actions.
Internally I would like to work with a Vector of Actions only.

```rust
struct Document {
  changes: ChangSet
}

struct ChangeSet(HashMap<String, Vec<Action>>);

enum Action {
  Add(Value),
  Remove(Value),
}
```

I tried to define a newtype for `Vec<Action>` and then implement `From<Sequence>` and `From<Action>` on it. But unfortunately, it looks like I can't define multiple `#[serde(from = "")]` on a container.

Alternatively, I tried to use `#[serde(deserialize_with = "")]` by doing something like:

```rust
struct Document {
  changes: ChangSet
}

struct ChangeSet(HashMap<String, ActionList);

#[serde(from = "ActionList_")]
struct ActionList(Vec<Action>);
impl From<ActionList_> for ActionList {
  ...
}

struct ActionList_ {
  #[serde(deserialize_with = "")]
  vec: Vec<Action>,
}

enum Action {
  Add(Value),
  Remove(Value),
}
```

But it gets pretty complicated really quickly and I still know how to conditionally deserialize both types.

Is there anything simpler alternative to always deserialize as a `Vec<Action>` even if the Value is a single `Action`?